# Bracket in F# ( let passFive f = (f 5) )

Tags: f#

`let passFive f = (f 5)`

`let passFive f = f 5`

What's difference between them?

I found they are both like below:

`val passFive : (int -> 'a) -> 'a`

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference?

Comment: A fair question no? Given an unknown language, and two different excerpts of code that both compile, it is reasonable to ask if there is a difference.

Comment: @Gabe: A prior encounter with Lisp? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both the same and brackets ( parentheses ) here are used like anywhere else where you want to group together the operands and increase their precedence.

```
printfn "%A" myfunc 5
```

will give error.

```
printfn "%A" (myfunc 5)
```

is how it is supposed to be written.

Comment: @Benjol: Like anywhere else in 90% of languages.

Comment: @delnan, ok, point taken. What I was thinking of was the fact that in F# brackets are *only* used for precedence, whereas elsewhere they're used to 'package' arguments for methods/functions. That sometimes trips people up.

Comment: @Benjol: Granted, but even then, many functional languages do this - the whole ML family, Haskell, several Haskell-derivates, Lisps, etc.